# ProActive Parallel Suite .NET alternative

Tags: .net, distributed-computing, proactive

I have recently started using ProActive Parallel Suite (http://proactive.inria.fr/). I was wondering if there are any alternatives for .NET Framework which are open-source and which have relatively the same feature set.

Answer (score 0):

Although not open source, Microsoft has announced that the Parallel Extensions to .NET will release as part of the .NET 4.0 Framework release. See the [Parallel Computing Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Parallel Extensions is a library that only deals with parallel multi-core computing. I'm more interested on the distributed computing functionality that Proactive provides.

Comment: I thought it did cover that from what I remembered of a .NET Rocks episode from a couple of years ago, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it did cover that from what I remembered of a .NET Rocks episode from a couple of years ago, sorry! – GraemeF

Your thinking correctly. .NET Rocks has covered parallelism several times. In particular, I recall one where the guest was a British guy who created a library called "Centipede" or something (no luck retracing that episode.)

Answer (score 0):

"I'm more interested on the distributed computing functionality that Proactive provides."

If I understand what you're looking for correctly, it's distributed objects.  You may want to look into CSLA here:http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/  I'm not sure how much(if any) it deals with the multi-core stuff.

It's for .NET and kept really up to date, with an active community.